# resize UISearchDisplayController dimmed black overlay

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

anybody know how to resize the dimmed black overly, once you clicked the search bar ?

i having problem when i clicked cancelled the tableview will expend then animated to disappear.

i using this to resize my result tableview.

```
-(void)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller didShowSearchResultsTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
   tableView.frame =fTableView.frame;//CGRectMake(26, 100, 280, 310); //fTableView.frame;
    tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:243.0/255.0 green:236.0/255.0 blue:212.0/255.0 alpha:1];   
}
```

when clicked on the search bar, gray overlay are full instead of my defined size.

[image]

[image]

when clicked cancel button, the view will expend back.
[image]

Comment: This answer from Tom Swift solved my problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4128659/675486

Answer (score 10):

I combined several answers in order to move the dimmed overlay frame.

1: override UISearchDisplayController class

```
@interface MySearchController : UISearchDisplayController
```

2: override setActive function

```
- (void)setActive:(BOOL)visible animated:(BOOL)animated
{
[super setActive: visible animated: animated];

//move the dimming part down
for (UIView *subview in self.searchContentsController.view.subviews) {
    //NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromClass([subview class]));
    if ([subview isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UISearchDisplayControllerContainerView")])
    {
        CGRect frame = subview.frame;
        frame.origin.y += 10;
        subview.frame = frame;
    }
}

}
```

3: change the xib/storyboard Search Display Controller from UISearchDisplayController to 
MySearchController

Comment: This is the best solution for this issue.  Thanks!

Comment: Does App Store approves it for the hack?

Answer (score 1):

I thought the searchDisplayController owned a seperate tableview, so my guess is that you would need to resize that one.

Something along the lines of: `<yourSearchViewController>.view.frame =self.tableView.frame;`

or if you don't have it as class variable, in a method which receives it as argument, eg:

```
-(void)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller didShowSearchResultsTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
   controller.view.frame = self.tableView.frame;
    tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:243.0/255.0 green:236.0/255.0 blue:212.0/255.0 alpha:1];   
}
```

Alternativily you might want to subclass it and override its view properties locally.

Hope this helps!

Comment: There is nothing like `view` in `UISearchDisplayController`. Your solution gives an error.

Comment: It was an indication as of what you should look for. If you spend a few minutes longer looking at the controllers properties, you'll notice it _does_ have the specific view under the name of 'searchResultsTableView'. source: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISearchDisplayController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: I went through the controller's `.h` file and found a `UIView * _view` but it seems its not exposed.

Comment: "you should try this because this may work and if that doesn't work then try this other thing" is more of a comment, not an answer

Comment: "you could do x, or if you want to do it properly you could do y." gives the op two options. I don't completely agree with your remark, but thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

The `UISearchDisplayController` does owns its own tableview which not as easy to tame.
I came across something like this and am still looking for a better solution.

```
-(void)searchDisplayControllerWillBeginSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller
{
    [controller.searchResultsTableView setDelegate:self];   
    CGFloat gr = 12.0;
    controller.searchResultsTableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:gr green:gr blue:gr alpha:0.0];
    [controller.searchResultsTableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
    CGRect searchTableFrame = CGRectMake(7, 105, 305, 292);
    [controller.searchResultsTableView setFrame:searchTableFrame];
}
```

The above code does sets the background to transparent but seems to silently ignore the frame size.

**EDIT:SOLVED**
I found the robust solution to this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388906/iphone-sdk-setting-the-size-of-uisearchdisplaycontrollers-table-view).
This saved my life.

Comment: Also I used custom cells that mock the look as if it it fits in required width properly.