# Restrict the overlay view frame in UISearchDispalyController

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I am using UISearchDisplayController when user type a keyword to search , an overlay view covers my view controller. I can not interact with my view controller, until i press the cancel button of search bar. 
I need to restrict the overlay view frame, so that I can interact with my view controller.

Comment: solution found . Now working perfectly fine.

Comment: solution : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7989273/resize-uisearchdisplaycontroller-dimmed-black-overlay