# Incorrect behaviour UISearchDisplayController. Please see screenshots

Tags: ios, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I need to resize UISearchBar of UISearchDisplayController. How can I do? Please see screenshots.

normal state

[image]

state after appearing UISearchDisplayController

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone SDK: Setting the size of UISearchDisplayController's table view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388906/iphone-sdk-setting-the-size-of-uisearchdisplaycontrollers-table-view)

Answer (score 0):

Ok I faced the same problem few days back and came with a work around

The problem occurs because the `UISearchbar` tends to take the superview's width after canceling the search. this can be avoided cleverly by giving your Searchbar a superview of desired width 
I am using the nib to do that.

I took a `UIView` with the required size
and added the 'UISeachbar` as a subclass to the view.
once the cancel is pressed the searchbar will now take the width of superview (which is a view of your desired size.)