# UISearchDisplayController's full-screen background intercepts touch events in iOS 7

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have a `UITableview` that doesn't take up the whole screen ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3P6B.png)). Everything worked fine in iOS 6. But in iOS 7, when the user searches, the search result table takes up the whole view ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EzsUw.png)).

To fix this, I tried setting the frame manually as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388906#2394784). The appearance is now correct ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqu9d.png)), but now the "<" button in the top left doesn't receive tap events when the search results table is displayed.

It seems the `searchResultsTableView` is adding a full-screen background view that is intercepting touch events. To prove this, I added this code to `didShowSearchResultsTableView`:

```
   controller.searchResultsTableView.superview.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];`
```

This [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8YS9f.png) confirms my hypothesis.

How can I fix this to allow the "<" button to receive tap events?
I want to avoid modifying `controller.searchResultsTableView.superview` so that my change doesn't break in future versions of iOS.

And what change in iOS 7 caused this behavior to start happening?

Comment: TIPS: It's a new standard in iOS 7 to always have the searchbar in the navigationbar. You can do that with `UISearchDisplayController.displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar = YES;` You can put a UIBarButton to show the searchbar.

Comment: It's unclear to me why you're getting those results. Filing a bug with a minimal sample app would be extremely useful.

Comment: thanks man your reasearch saved my lot of time.. could solve [my](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19291670/mapview-not-scrollable-touchable-in-ios-7) problem

Answer (score 2):

I am still searching for a better solution, but currently my solution is in the viewControllers `viewDidLayoutSubviews` tell your view to move to front. The code would look something like this.

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.navigationBar];
}
```