# Mapview not scrollable & touchable with UISearchDisplayController in iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, dictionary, ios7

I am using `UISearchDisplaycontroller`.. In my viewcontroller user can search place aftert i have update mapview and setting searchtableview hidden propety is YES.

In iOS 7 I am not able to scroll and get touch event on mapview. But in iOS 6 it will work..

After pressing cancel button i am able to scroll and touch event on map view. You can see below screenshot.

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could solve my problem with help of another question [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18924651/uisearchdisplaycontrollers-full-screen-background-intercepts-touch-events-in-io)

by setting `self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView.superview.hidden = YES`

it worked for me..

View hierarchy for iOS 7 is changed..

Comment: thanks very much, solved my problem. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19341589/uiscrollview-frozen-when-uisearchdisplaycontroller-is-active)