# UISearchBar seems to disable UIBarButtonItems in Navigation and Toolbar under iOS7

Tags: ios7, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

I have a view controller with a navigation bar at the top and a toolbar at the bottom with a table view in the center. The table view has a search bar and scope bar. The user can use the search, or not. When done searching the user select items from the resulting list and then selects a button in the toolbar to move to the next view controller using a segue. Everything is constructed using storyboards. The layout, functionality and workflow works fine under iOS 6.

Under iOS 7 the layout, functionality, and workflow work fine w/o search (i.e., the user simply selects items from the table). The search mechanism also works fine, but the 'Done' button in the navigation bar, and the 'Select' button in the toolbar are disabled (i.e., the prepareForSegue method isn't entered). If I select cancel in the search bar the search results are lost but the workflow is again functional (i.e., the buttons are enabled and prepareForSegue is entered as expected).

I tried implementing the UISearchBar searchBarTextDidEndEditing and searchBarSearchButtonClicked methods and making sure they are invoked in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method. These changes had no positive or negative effect. I also experimented with some of the features of the view controller, thinking that maybe the search results were in some way obscuring my navigation and toolbar buttons but that didn't work either.

I haven't found a reference to anyone else encountering this kind of problem.

Comment: I built a sample app to test this problem out. It is a tabbed app with one of the tabs going to a table view. That view dispatches through segue to another table view with the search control. This second view dispatches to a 3rd view with a table. All of the table views are UIViews with embedded tables.

The behavior is only slightly different than reported above. When the search is invoked, the entire navigation bar and toolbar disappear (whereas in my full application they remain but do not respond to events). If I cancel the search the navigation and tool bars reappear and are functional.

Comment: I found another question ([Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18924651/uisearchdisplaycontrollers-full-screen-background-intercepts-touch-events-in-io)) that describes the same problem. The search results table frame can be made smaller so that the navigation and toolbar bars aren't obscured but they aren't able to respond to touch events.

Comment: I submitted this as a bug to Apple along with a sample project demonstrating the problem back in January. They haven't gotten around to testing it (more than asking me if the problem still exists in 7.1, which they could find out on their own w/o asking since they have the test project). I am surprised no one here has encountered this problem.

Comment: I have a similar problem. Did you resolve this?